# How to get result code in onDestroy()?

Tags: android

When my activity is destroyed, I want to check if the result code is `RESULT_OK` to do some cleanup. There is a `setResult` method, but no getter.

How do I check - *from within the activity* - if the activity is going to be finished with `RESULT_OK`?

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (isFinishing()) {
        if (???result??? == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do directly inside the `onDestroy` and you should not rely on it. The result code is a formal parameter of the `onActivityResult` callback. If you want to check its value inside the `onDestroy` you could store it in a variable with the class scope.

Comment: Consider a derived class from an `Activity` with no available source code. Are you saying I must perform the cleanup in `onActivityResult` in the parent activity?